# Same View, different displays, One page, same exposed filters. Possible?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to list my content categorically within view. The problem is that I want all of it to be filtered through exposed filters.

Here is what Content Type looks like:-

### Content Type (MyContent)

- Title
- Body
- Category `(it has three categories in it "Category1, Category2 and Category 3". User has to selects one when entering the content)`

Now I created a view which lists all of the content linearly (like a normal list) and I have exposed filters on top, which filter the content, but now I am not sure how to proceed when I have to show the content as:-

[image]

Any Idea what I should do to achieve this? What should I do in this scenario?

I'll be grateful to you valuable assistance.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your results together. Under the Format option in views next to your format type (unformatted list, etc...) click on Settings.

In this menu you'll see "Grouping field" this will allow you to specify on which fields your results should be grouped. The field needs to already be included in your display.

Once you enable this you'll probably notice that that field is now displayed twice. You can just go into that field and check "Exclude from Display"